# Gaussian blur in C++

Tags: c++, gaussianblur

I'm trying to implement Gaussian blur in C++. However, it looks like regardless of radius, I always get a blur with radius ~3. I suppose this may have something to do with alpha premultiplying, but I'm unable to figure out, what am I doing wrong.

The implementation looks like following:

```
extern "C" void __cdecl GaussianBlur(unsigned char* bitmapData, 
    int stride, 
    int width, 
    int height, 
    int radius)
{
    // Gaussian kernel

    int diameter = 2 * radius + 1;
    std::shared_ptr<float[]> kernel = generateGaussKernel(diameter);

    // Blur

    auto copy = std::shared_ptr<unsigned char[]>(new unsigned char[height * stride]);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        memcpy(copy.get() + y * stride, bitmapData + y * stride, width * BYTES_PER_PIXEL);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            Color sum;
            float weight = 0.0f;
            int count = 0;

            int xStart = x - radius;
            int xEnd = x + radius;
            int yStart = y - radius;
            int yEnd = y + radius;

            for (int x1 = xStart; x1 <= xEnd; x1++)
                for (int y1 = yStart; y1 <= yEnd; y1++)
                {
                    // Find weight

                    int kernelX = x1 - xStart;
                    int kernelY = y1 - yStart;
                    float kernelValue = kernel[kernelY * diameter + kernelX];

                    // Premultiply alpha

                    Color color;
                    if (x1 >= 0 && x1 < width && y1 >= 0 && y1 < height)
                        color = getColor(copy.get(), stride, x1, y1);
                    else
                        color = Color(0);

                    sum.R += (float)(color.R * color.A) * kernelValue;
                    sum.G += (float)(color.G * color.A) * kernelValue;
                    sum.B += (float)(color.B * color.A) * kernelValue;
                    sum.A += color.A * kernelValue;

                    weight += kernelValue;
                    count++;
                }

            if (count > 0)
            {
                Color result;
                result.A = sum.A / weight;

                if (result.A > 0)
                {
                    result.R = ((sum.R / weight) / result.A);
                    result.G = ((sum.G / weight) / result.A);
                    result.B = ((sum.B / weight) / result.A);
                }

                setColor(bitmapData, stride, x, y, result);
            }
        }
}
```

Gauss kernel genration is implemented as following:

```
std::shared_ptr<float[]> generateGaussKernel(int diameter)
{
    float sigma = 1;
    std::shared_ptr<float[]> kernel(new float[diameter * diameter]);
    int mean = diameter / 2;
    float sum = 0.0; // For accumulating the kernel values
    for (int x = 0; x < diameter; ++x)
        for (int y = 0; y < diameter; ++y) {
            kernel[y * diameter + x] = (float)(exp(-0.5 * (pow((x - mean) / sigma, 2.0) + pow((y - mean) / sigma, 2.0))) / (2 * M_PI * sigma * sigma));

            // Accumulate the kernel values
            sum += kernel[y * diameter + x];
        }

    // Normalize the kernel
    for (int x = 0; x < diameter; ++x)
        for (int y = 0; y < diameter; ++y)
            kernel[y * diameter + x] /= sum;

    return kernel;
}
```

And utils (if relevant):

```
const int BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 4;
const int B_OFFSET = 0;
const int G_OFFSET = 1;
const int R_OFFSET = 2;
const int ALPHA_OFFSET = 3;

inline float getAlpha(unsigned char* bitmap, int stride, int x, int y)
{
    return bitmap[y * stride + x * BYTES_PER_PIXEL + ALPHA_OFFSET] / 255.0f;
}

inline Color getColor(unsigned char* bitmap, int stride, int x, int y)
{
    Color result;
    result.A = bitmap[y * stride + x * BYTES_PER_PIXEL + ALPHA_OFFSET] / 255.0f;
    result.R = bitmap[y * stride + x * BYTES_PER_PIXEL + R_OFFSET];
    result.G = bitmap[y * stride + x * BYTES_PER_PIXEL + G_OFFSET];
    result.B = bitmap[y * stride + x * BYTES_PER_PIXEL + B_OFFSET];

    return result;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit:** How the function is called:

```cs
[DllImport("Animator.Engine.Native.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void GaussianBlur(IntPtr bitmapData,
    int stride,
    int width,
    int height,
    int radius);

//(...)

internal override void Apply(BitmapBuffer framebuffer, BitmapBuffer backBuffer, BitmapBuffer frontBuffer, BitmapBufferRepository repository)
{
    var data = framebuffer.Bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, framebuffer.Bitmap.Width, framebuffer.Bitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    ImageProcessing.GaussianBlur(data.Scan0, 
        data.Stride, 
        data.Width, 
        data.Height, 
        Radius);

        framebuffer.Bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

The (faulty) effect:

[image: Faulty effect]

---

**Edit 3**

The whole project is opensource, link to repo: https://gitlab.com/spook/Animator.git

If you want to test it, run `Animator.Editor/Animator.Editor` project with the following example xml:

```xml
<Movie>
    <Movie.Config>
        <MovieConfig FramesPerSecond="30" Height="200" Width="200" />
    </Movie.Config>
    
    <Scene Name="Scene1" Background="White">
        <Rectangle Position="0;0" Width="20" Height="20" Brush="Red">
            <Rectangle.Effects>
                <GaussianBlurEffect Radius="7" />
            </Rectangle.Effects>
        </Rectangle>
    </Scene>
</Movie>
```

Comment: Where do you call function `GaussianBlur`?

Comment: @paladin, P/invoked from C# code.

Comment: What I wanted to say is, "What if function `GaussianBlur` is always called with `int radius = 3`?" Please check this first.

Comment: @paladin, it is not. I checked that in the native code, radius is passed properly.

Comment: This looks suspicious: `float kernelValue = kernel[kernelY * diameter + kernelX];` (within your loop)

Comment: Also `int kernelX = x1 - xStart;` and `int kernelY = y1 - yStart;` within your loop are looking suspicious.

Comment: Also, please never use a loop without `{...}` -> `for (int x1 = xStart; x1 <= xEnd; x1++)`.

Comment: @paladin, Why? Kernel is stored row-by-row and each row has width of `diamater`. And since `x1` goes from `xStart` to `xEnd`, effectively it goes from `0` to `2 * radius + 1 = diameter`

Comment: I said it looks suspicious, because declaring variables within a loop is often a bug. Are you checking for the array bounds for `kernel[kernelY * diameter + kernelX]`?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to not use Fourier Trasform?

Comment: @Eddymage Fourier Transformation is slow?!

Comment: @paladin Maybe, it depends on the dimension of the data and if they are of dimension 2^n. But if you use some library such as FFTW I think it is more reliable and easy to code than implementing all the sums.

Answer (score 1):

The error was in the way Gaussian kernel was generated:

```
std::shared_ptr<float[]> generateGaussKernel(int diameter)
{
    float sigma = 1;
```

Having constant `sigma`, the Gaussian bell's shape was always the same, regardless of kernel size. It was just needed to fix it to:

```
std::shared_ptr<float[]> generateGaussKernel(int diameter)
{
    float sigma = diameter / 4.0f;
```

...to make it work.